# How can I make this sum of perfect squares function more efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop

Part of my homework involves making a function which checks if a number is a sum of two squares. Problem is that it takes a very long time for larger numbers to run through it. Any suggestions on how to make this more efficient? for example, given the number `50` it would return `(7,1)` since 7^2 is 49 and 1^2 is 1 so the total would be 50
Here's the code:

```
def sum_of_squares(n) : 
  i = 1 

  while i * i <= n : 
      j = 1

      while(j * j <= n) : 

          while (i * i + j * j == n) : 

              return (j,i)

          j = j + 1
      i = i + 1
```

Comment: Theres quite a lot of optimization techniques that could be mentioned, which leads to this question becoming a tad bit open-ended.

Comment: sorry, fairly new to python, what kind of optimization techniques could be mentioned?

Comment: Memoiziation comes to mind. Perhaps also using `sqrt` and `floor`? A better way to see what parts of your code actually need optimising would be to use `timeit` or some other type of profiling

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com is where you should post this question

Comment: [More Optimized Technique with Python Code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-number-can-represented-sum-two-squares/)

Comment: You can eliminate all multiplications. The sequence of squares is just the accumulated sums of the odd integers, since `(i+1)**2 == i**2 + 2*i + 1`. In Python 3.8, `[square := (square + i) for i in range(1,n,2)]`, or in any recent version of Python, `list(itertools.accumulate(range(1,n,2), operator.add))`

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_of_squares(n) :
  range = round(math.sqrt(n)) 
  i = 1 
  while i <= round(range/2) : 
      j = range;

      while(j >= round(range/2)) : 

          while (i * i + j * j == n) : 

              return (j,i)

          j = j - 1
      i = i + 1
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Your post will make a bit more sense to the OP if you elaborate a little on your solution. Just giving pure code is kind of beyond the point of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

A modification of algorithm from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-number-can-represented-sum-two-squares/

1. Method 1--saves squares in a dictionary for later lookup
2. Method 2--computes integer square root using binary search
3. Method 3--checks if the number is a perfect square by using
   math.sqrt function

**Method 1**

The technique is basically to loop through numbers from 0 to sqrt(n), storing the  squares i * i as dictionary key, with i as value.

If number (n - i * i) already in the dictionary, then you have found a pair (i &  d[n - i * i].

Returns the solution with the max tuple value.

Algorithm complexity O(sqrt(n)).

```
def sum_square(n): 
  d = {}
  maxi = None
  for i in range(n): 
    if i * i > n: 
      break
      # store squared value with value in dictionary 
    d[i*i] = i  # saving the square root of i*i as i

    try:
      k = d[n - i*i]      # check if n- i*i is already in a key
      if maxi:
        maxi = max(maxi, (i, k))    # update max solution
      else:
        maxi = (i, k)               # first solution
    except:
      continue

  return maxi
```

**Method 2**

```
def sum_square_binary(n): 
  def binary_search(start_, end_, val): 
    # If lower limit exceeds   
    # upper limit.  
    if start_ > end_: 
        return None 

    # Calculating mid.  
    mid = start_ + (end_ - start_) // 2 

    if mid * mid == val:
        return mid 

    if mid * mid > val: 
        return binary_search(start_, mid - 1, val)

    return binary_search(mid + 1, end_, val)

  maxi = None

  for i in range(n):
      if i*i > n:
          break

      b = n - i * i 

      # Use binary search to see if b is a perfect square
      # only need to check range [0, b] in binary search
      k = binary_search(0, b, b)  # k is the root of b (if perfect square)
      if k:
          maxi = max(maxi, (i, k), key = max) if maxi else (i, k)

  return (max(maxi), min(maxi)) if maxi else maxi
```

**Method 3**

```
import math

def sum_square_sqrt(n):
  def integer_sqrt(x): 
      """ Returns sqrt of integer if it is a perfect square.  
          Uses technique from Cook https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/11/17/fast-way-to-test-whether-a-number-is-a-square/ to reduce the number of times sqrt is called """
      # Find the floating point value of  
      # square root of x. 
      h = x & 0xF
      if h > 9:
          return None
      if ( h != 2 and h != 3 and h != 5 and h != 6 and h != 7 and h != 8 ):
          sr = math.sqrt(x) 

          # If square root is an integer 
          return int(sr) if ((sr - math.floor(sr)) == 0) else None
      else:
          return None

  maxi = None

  for i in range(n):
      if i*i > n:
          break

      b = n - i * i 

      # Use binary search to see if b is a perfect square
      # only need to check range [0, b] in binary search
      k = integer_sqrt(b)  # k is the root of b (if perfect square)
      if k:
          maxi = max(maxi, (i, k), key = max) if maxi else (i, k)

  return (max(maxi), min(maxi)) if maxi else maxi
```

**Performance**

Method 1 using a dictionary is much faster, with Method 3 comparable.
Method 3 should be okay until the sqrt becomes inaccurate as a test for larger n.

```
tst = [randint(1e6, 1e9) for _ in range(10)]

%timeit for k in tst: sum_square(k)
```

**>>>Method 1: 180 ms ± 14.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)**

```
%timeit for k in tst: sum_square_binary(k)
```

**>>>Method 2: 4.04 s ± 97.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)**

```
%timeit for k in tst: sum_square_sqrt(k)
```

**>>>Method 3: 192 ms ± 5.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)**

Comment: Needs to be a `dict` so you can return the sqrt of `n-i*i`

Comment: @o11c--I was cheating and returning the two squares.  Guess I'll make it a dict and return the two actual numbers.

Comment: @o11c--thanks, updated to use a dictionary to return the pairs rather than the squares.

Comment: @DarrylG This works but my functions requirements is that it wants the return the way that maximizes the larger number. For the example of the integer 50, I'd like it to return (7,1) instead of (5,5)

Comment: @piethon--updated so it returns the max tuple--so in this case return (7, 1) for 50.

Comment: @DarrylG Function works efficiently and runs for all the test cases properly but it does not want to pass a tester that was provided to us. Is there another approach for this without using dictionaries?

Comment: @piethon--yes, there is.  I'll update my answer with a method that is O(sqrt(n)*log(n)).

Comment: @piethon--updated my answer with two additional methods that don't require a dictionary.  You may try Method 3 first.

Comment: @DarrylG Do I have to import anything for methods 2 or 3? they seem to be giving me errors when I try to run them

Comment: @piethon--I updated post.  Can you try again?  Sorry, but I previously didn't copy/paste properly from my Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score -1):

You could use dynamic programming, to prevent squares from being recalculated over and over. By using a keeping track of a list of outcomes you can just look up the value. If the value is not defined yet, you just calculate it once, if it has been calculated before, you just return the corresponding entry in the list instead of recalculating:

```
squares = []

def get_square(x):
    global squares

    if(squares[x] == -1):
        squares[x] = x * x

    return squares[x]

def sum_of_squares(n):
    global squares
    squares = [-1 for i in range(n)]

    i = 1
    while get_square(i) <= n - 1: 
        j = 1
        while(get_square(j) <= n - 1) :
            if(get_square(i) + get_square(j) == n) :
                return (j,i)
            j = j + 1
        i = i + 1

print(sum_of_squares(25))
```

Comment: Multiplication is very cheap; hashtable lookups are much more expensive.

Answer (score -1):

As some others suggested above, preventing the computation of squares in each iteration is a good start. Here is a simple implementation using for loops :

```
def sum_of_squares(n):
     lim = int(n**0.5)+1
     for i in range(1, lim):
             for j in range(1,i):
                     if(i**2 + j**2==n):
                             return (i,j)
```

Comment: Your `lim` approach is actually worse than the original. Your decrease in iterations of `j` reduces the constant factor, but it's still quadratic complexity.